# EntityManager dont merge

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

the test junit adds a new role instead of updating(it does not update).i use spring, hibernate, maven, Mysql.someone has an idea?.thanks:

TestJunit.java:

```
.........
public class TestJunit {

@Test
public void UpdateRole() {
    InterfAdminMetier metier = (InterfAdminMetier) context
            .getBean("metier");
    Role r = metier.getRole("ROLE_Test");
    System.out.println("1 before update************************************"+r.getRoleName());
    r.setRoleName("ROLE_TestUpdate");
    metier.updateRole(r);
    System.out.println("2 after update************************************"+metier.getRole("ROLE_Test").getRoleName());
    assertTrue(metier.getRole("ROLE_TestUpdate").getRoleName().contentEquals("ROLE_TestUpdate"));

}
}
```

User.java:

```
    ........
//import org.hibernate.mapping.Set;


/*classe JavaBean:les propriétes ne sont accessible que par les gettters et les setters
il faut definir un constructeur sans parametres si non il ne sera pas defini par defaut si nous deffinision un 
constructeur avec parametres*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private String mail;
    private String pw;

    /*
     * un utilisateur peut avoir plusieurs role comme l'admin qui a les roles
     * admin, biblio, enseignant, etud un role peut etre attribuer a plusieurs
     * utili comme roleEtudiant
     */


/*  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "roles_users",  joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "idUser", nullable = false, updatable = true) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roleName",
                    nullable = false, updatable = true) })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);*/


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "roles_users", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idUser", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = true) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roleName", referencedColumnName = "roleName", nullable = false, updatable = true) })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);
       ........................................
    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    ..........................................

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getPw() {
        return pw;
    }

    public void setPw(String pw) {
        this.pw = pw;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    ...................................

}
```

Role.java:

```
        ............
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "roles")
    public class Role implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "roleName")
        private String roleName;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")
        private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(0);

        /*
         * @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles") private
         * Collection<User> users;
         */

        public Role() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public Role(String roleName) {
            super();
            this.roleName = roleName;
        }

        public Collection<User> getUsers() {
            return users;
        }

        public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
            this.users = users;
        }

        public String getRoleName() {
            return roleName;
        }

        public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
            this.roleName = roleName;
        }

    }
```

BiblioDaoImplementation.java:

```
    ...........
public class BiblioDaoImplementation implements InterfaBiblioDao {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "UP_Biblio")
    private EntityManager em;


//  ---------------------------------------user---------------------------------    
    @Override
    public String addUser(User user) {

        em.persist(user);

        return user.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public String removeUser(String id) {

        User user = getUser(id);
        em.remove(user);

        return user.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public String updateUser(User user) {

        em.merge(user);

        return user.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String Id) {

        return em.find(User.class, Id);
    }

    @Override
    public void attrubierRoleToUser(Role role, String id) {

        User u = em.find(User.class, id);

        u.getRoles().add(role);

    }

    @Override
    public List<User> listUsers() {

        Query req = em
                .createQuery("select user from User user");

        return req.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> listUserByRole(String roleName) {

        Query req = em
                .createQuery(" SELECT u FROM Role r JOIN r.users u  WHERE r.roleName=:x");

        req.setParameter("x", roleName);

        return req.getResultList();
    }

//  ---------------------------------------role---------------------------------
    @Override
    public String addRole(Role role) {

        em.persist(role);

        return role.getRoleName();
    }

    @Override
    public String removeRole(String roleName) {
        Role role = em.find(Role.class, roleName);
        em.remove(role);

        return roleName;
    }

    @Override
    public String updateRole(Role role) {

        em.merge(r);



        return role.getRoleName();
    }


    @Override
    public Role getRole(String roleName) {

        return em.find(Role.class, roleName);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Role> listRoles() {

        Query req = em.createQuery("select role from Role role");

        return req.getResultList();
    }
    }
```

persistence.xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
      <persistence-unit name="UP_Biblio" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
           <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

      <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/biblioissteg"></property>
      <property name="username" value="root"></property>
      <property name="password" value=""></property>
      </bean>


      <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
      <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
     <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
        <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="UP_Biblio"></property>
    </bean>


        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
        <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

       <bean id="dao" class="tn.issteg.biblio.dao.BiblioDaoImplementation"></bean>
       <bean id="metier" class="tn.issteg.biblio.metier.BiblioMetierImpl">
          <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
       </bean>

    </beans>
```

console:
................
INFO : org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator - Checking whether login URL '/login' is accessible with your configuration
Hibernate: select role0_.roleName as roleName2_0_ from roles role0_ where role0_.roleName=?
1avant up************************************ROLE_Test
Hibernate: select role0_.roleName as roleName2_0_ from roles role0_ where role0_.roleName=?
Hibernate: insert into roles (roleName) values (?)
Hibernate: select role0_.roleName as roleName2_0_ from roles role0_ where role0_.roleName=?
2apres up************************************ROLE_Test
Hibernate: select role0_.roleName as roleName2_0_ from roles role0_ where role0_.roleName=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are changing the Role Name, which is the identifier of the Role class, hence a new role is created, if you change anything but the identifier it will be updated

Comment: I think what you are saying is **true**, so I have to add another field (**idRole**) to the **Role class** and will be **ID**, no other mean to do the update ? for this case (**Role**) it is possible, but if we want to modify the **id** of a **user** for example, then it is not possible! I think it does not make sense

Comment: Actually choosing the identifier depends on your logic, your data model and your business model ... what you think it should be the identifier should be -well- the identifier and hence it can't be changed per the same entity, whatever editable field can't be the identifier ... so if you think it's appropriate to add an ID field (as you need the role name to be editable) then go for it ... If you think that the user ID should be editable, you will need to choose another identifier .. It all depends upon your logic .. hope it helps

Comment: And if you think the answer is correct, you can gracefully accept it as the correct answer :)

Comment: thanks, "the identifier and hence it can't be changed per the **same entity**", can it be modified by another entity? please explain this or documentation for this item

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `update` instead of `merge` :

```
   public String updateRole(Role role) {

         em.update(role);
    return role.getRoleName();
     }
```

Comment: thanks, but eclipse does not offer me update, and when I enter it, it tells me an error, and it suggests a cast to em .....

Comment: The thing is that merge can't find the object to update so can you test the `getRole` methode before and see if it's green

Comment: in the junit test I call the method **getRole** before and after the update, you can see the **console**(outpout):`1-befort update************************************ROLE_Test
Hibernate: select role0_.roleName as roleName6_0_ from roles role0_ where role0_.roleName=?
Hibernate: select role0_.roleName as roleName6_0_ from roles role0_ where role0_.roleName=?
2-after update************************************ROLE_Test`